How do Application Load Balancers maintain high availability without a stable IP address?
Amazon's Application Load Balancers (ALBs) are AWS's default HTTP load balancer, but they don't have static IP addresses. Instead they are given a generated domain name (e.g. myservice-12345678.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com.) which always points to the latest ALB IP addresses.
The recommendation is then to use Route53 to point your actual domain name (e.g. service.example.com) at this generated ALB domain name using a CNAME record (or an ALIAS record for apex domains).
It's important not to use an A record to point to the ALB's IP addresses directly from the main domain, because when the dynamic ALB IP address changes, the main domain would then fail to point anywhere, bringing down the service until someone explicitly updates the DNS.
Setting this up with CNAME leads to DNS looking as follows:
$ dig service.example.com
...
;; ANSWER SECTION:
service.example.com. 300 IN CNAME myservice-12345678.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com.
myservice-12345678.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com. 60 IN A 52.121.11.212
myservice-12345678.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com. 60 IN A 18.112.21.121

But, if those IPs may change then I don't understand how this is stable even with the initial CNAME. Clients will still have cached the secondary step from myservice-12345678.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com -> 52.121.11.212 for 60 seconds (or more if they ignore the TTL).
Doesn't this mean that if the IP address of one of those ALB nodes changes then clients may have broken connections for up to a minute? (The round-robin DNS setup doesn't offer any reliable protection against this)
Unless Amazon are carefully doing rolling deployments of new ALB nodes, leaving the old nodes up for at least 60 seconds after the ALB DNS has been changed. I could well believe this, but I've been searching for hours and I can't find any allusion to it working this way. I also can't find any information on how often these IP addresses may actually change, or what might trigger a change.
Does anyone know how (or if) Amazon make ALBs reliable in this way?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35317682/175990

Thanks @GregAskew, that is very helpful. I've now read that answer, the linked blog post, and the official AWS post about ELB best practice. They explain why the IP addresses aren't static - to allow for scaling - and presumably this is therefore the only reason IPs would change. None of them quite give the confirmation I was looking for (that ALBs will only be removed more than 60 seconds after their IP was removed from DNS), but the in-depth scaling behaviour in their design does certainly suggest that they would be doing this.

@GregAskew feel free to write an answer along the lines of this ^ and I'll accept it. Otherwise I can just write it myself.
